# Parse Json data to extract an array from a object

Tags: android, json, api, parsing, android-studio

```
    {
      "total_hits": 20277,
  "max_score": 10.676512,
  "hits": [
    {
      "_id": "513fceb375b8dbbc21000022",
      "fields": {
        "item_name": "Cheddar Cheese - 1 cup, diced",
        "brand_name": "USDA",
        "nf_calories": 531.96,
        "nf_total_fat": 43.74
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "513fceb375b8dbbc2100001d",
      "fields": {
        "item_name": "Cheddar Cheese - 1 slice (1 oz)",
        "brand_name": "USDA",
        "nf_calories": 112.84,
        "nf_total_fat": 9.28
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

the above is my json returned from an api

```
 JSONObject raintopLevel = new JSONObject(rainbuilder.toString());

                      String listArray = raintopLevel.getString("hits");
```

I am returning that a JSON object "hits" using the code attached what i want to do however is access the "fields" array in side this object but i have been unable to do this 
any help is apprecited

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample code to show how the `org.json` API is used:

```
    JSONObject raintopLevel = new JSONObject(rainbuilder.toString());
    JSONArray hits = raintoplevel.getJSONArray("hits");
    JSONObject obj = hits.getJSONObject(0); // first object in array
    String id = obj.getString("_id");
    JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject("fields");
    String itemName = obj2.getString("item_name");
```

Comment: Thank you very much It works i can now work with this appreciate it @kris larson

Answer (score 0):

"hits" is a JSONArray, so you have to use JSONArray

```
JSONArray raintopLevel = rainbuilder.getJSONArray("hits");
```

then you can iterate the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < raintopLevel.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json_hits = raintopLevel.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = json_id.getString("_id");
    JSONArray ja_fields= json_id.getJSONObject("fields");
    String item_name = ja_fields.getString("item_name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"hits" is not JSONObject, It is JSONArray.
So you need to use JSONArray.
You can use following code.

```
JSONObject raintopLevel = new JSONObject(rainbuilder.toString());
JSONArray hits = raintoplevel.getJSONArray("hits");

JSONObject object11 = hits.getJSONObject(0); // for "hits"
String id = object11.getString("_id");

JSONObject object22 = object11.getJSONObject("fields"); // for "fields" that is inside "hits"
String item_name = object22.getString("item_name");
String brand_name = object22.getString("brand_name");
```